# Reload $(document).ready(); functions when AJAX has loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am currently skinning an application where I have no access to the markup or scripts apart from one CSS file and on JS file so I can add my own styles and functions. Not an ideal set-up I know but believe me it's not my choice. Oh and all the content on this site is generated via AJAX requests, nice.

Anyway, the problem is that I have a lot of Javascript that needs to run on `$(document).ready();` but as the page never really reloads (due to the AJAX), none of the code gets executed.

Is there a way I can set all the functions in `$(document).ready();` to run everytime the AJAX call has been completed?

I've included the built in AJAX call (that I cannot edit) below.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  url: url1,
  data: pars,
  success: function(data)
  {
    $('#thisContent').html(data);
    loadMenu(urlToLoad);
  } 
});
```

Comment: You could call the $(document).ready() handler at the end of the success handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add a handler for [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/). It is called after every ajax call is finished (either successfully or with error).

Further reading: [Ajax Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events)

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is for the handler of the `$(document).ready([handler])` event to be called again you could just use a named function as handler, and reference that:

```
$(document).ready(function readyHandler()
{
});
//and:
$.ajax({....,success:readyHandler});
```

But, personally, I'd recommend you to think about this. If, for example, the `$.ajax` call is made in the `readyHandler` function, you're going to create a deadlock. You're also quite likely to make the same binds over and over again. I don't know what you're trying to achieve but I'm pretty sure that there's a better way to do it. (If indeed I understood your question correctly)

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) can be useful for you.